# A geometric proof of the Gauss-Lucas theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, riemannian-geometry, polynomials, hyperbolic-geometry

Motivated by a [geometric proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Geometric_proofs) we ask:

Is there a geometric proof for the [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem)? Since we are working on a half plane, can one imagine a possible proof of the above fact  with some methods in hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: The Gauss-Lucas theorem has nothing particular to do with half-planes, it concerns any convex subset of the plane.

Comment: @abx  Yes but an equivalent formulation is the following: If all roots  of  a polynomial lie at a half plane, then all roots of its derivative lie at the same half plane(See the  Ahlfors book, complex analysis).

Comment: @abx I don't see the point of your objection - convex subsets of the plane have a lot to do with half-planes!

Comment: @abx actually, it does: I recently gave a proof of GL via the numerical range of a matrix, which involves half-planes (see my answer below for details).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good question! I think the following article may qualify as a "yes":

Arnaud Ch´eritat, Yan Gao, Yafei Ou, Lei Tan. "A refinement of the Gauss-Lucas theorem (after
W. P. Thurston)". 2015. 
https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01157602/document

(An essential observation here is that you **can** make the Gauss-Lucas theorem explicitly about the behavior half-planes in $\mathbb{C}$. )

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for  your very  perfect  and  interesting  answer.

Answer (score 11):

I think the problem with that is that the theorem is so easy (close to trivial really) that there's no need for any tools. If we want to work in a zero free half plane, then the following simple argument settles matters immediately: Assume, for convenience, that $p\not=0$ on $\mathbb C^+ =\{ z: \textrm{Im}\, z> 0\}$. If we write $p(z)=c\prod (z-a_j)$, then
$$
\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \sum \frac{1}{z-a_j} .
$$
Since $\textrm{Im}\, 1/(z-a)<0$ for $z\in\mathbb C^+$ if $\textrm{Im}\, a\le 0$, it follows that $p'/p$ has no zeros in $\mathbb C^+$, either.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer.But I search for a proof with a serious usage og a riemanian metric or some thing in the upper half plane as the main object of poin care plane. I guess that yourmethod is similar to the book of Ahlfors

Comment: @AliTaghavi Why do you want or hope that something with a direct proof should have a proof using some complicated tools? Not everything to do with a half-plane is to do with hyperbolic space

Answer (score 6):

I gave a simple geometric proof of Bocher's theorem (a generalization of the Gauss-Lucas theorem) in a paper in Computational Methods and Function Theory in 2015.  You can find a pdf at my webpage linked [here](https://trevorjrichards.com/research-interests-and-publications/).  The paper is the one titled

- "Level curve configurations and conformal equivalence of meromorphic functions"

It is a long paper (48 pages), but the proof of Bocher's theorem is entirely contained on page 6.

The idea is as follows.  Suppose that a rational function $R(z)$ has all of its zeros contained in one disk $D_1$ on the Riemann sphere, and all of its poles on another disk $D_2$, and that $D_1\cap D_2=\emptyset$.  Bocher's theorem says that there will be no critical point of $R$ outside of $D_1\cup D_2$.  This immediately implies the Gauss--Lucas theorem.

**PROOF:** Suppose that there is a critical point $z_0$ of $R$ outside of $D_1\cup D_2$.  We may as well assume that $z_0=0$, and that $D_1$ is contained in the half-plane $\{z:Re(z)<-1\}$ and that $D_2$ is contained in the half-plane $\{z:Re(z)>1\}$.

Define $\epsilon=|R(0)|$, and consider the level set $\mathcal{L}=\{z:|R(z)|=\epsilon\}$.  Since $0$ is a critical point of $R$, $\mathcal{L}$ has a branching at $0$.  In fact, if $0$ is a critical point of $R$ of multiplicity $k$, then $\mathcal{L}$ has a $(2k+2)$--fold branching at $0$.  Thus there is some horizontal line segment $H_m=\{x+im:-1\leq x\leq1\}$ which intersects $\mathcal{L}$ in at least two points distinct, say $z_1$ and $z_2$, with $Re(z_1)<Re(z_2)$.  However since $z_1$ is closer to every zero and further from every pole of $R$ than $z_2$, it must be that $|R(z_1)|<|R(z_2)|$, contradicting the assumption that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are in the same level set of $R$.

Comment: Thank you  so much for  your  very interesting  answer  and your  elegant result on generalization of  Gauss  Lucas theorem. My apology that I  did not pay attention to the  details, however  I have given my  +1, with my most  pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

I think (but am not sure), that the first and most enlightening proof is due to Gauss himself: The derivative of a polynomial is given by

$$
f^\prime(z) = f(z) \sum \frac1{z-a_i},
$$

where the $a_i$ are the zeros. So, thinking of point charges at $a_i,$ with Coulomb repulsion, the critical points are where the Coulomb forces balance. This can obviously only happen in the convex hull of the zeros.

Answer (score 4):

[Charles R. Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Royal_Johnson) and I gave a proof of the Gauss–Lucas theorem that utilizes the *[field of values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range)* (or *numerical range*) of a matrix, which can be viewed as geometric in nature (the field itself is an uncountably infinite intersection of half-planes). The proof can be found in the article *[Matricial Proofs of Some Classical Results about Critical Point Location](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2020.1671740)*, which recently appeared in *The American Mathematical Monthly*.

Our methods also yield a proof of [Marden's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem) and a weaker version of Siebeck's theorem.